# Send email in HTML with Amazon SES API and PHP

Tags: php, html-email, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send a piece of html email but does not work. The html is not interpreted in the email that arrives. Can anyone tell me why? Below is the code I'm using to send the email:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
$client = SesClient::factory(array(
                'key' => '....',
                'secret' => '....',
                'region'  => 'us-west-2'
            ));


$result = $client->sendEmail(array(
    'Source' => 'test <test@test.com.br>',
    'Destination' => array(
        'ToAddresses' => array('test@test.com')
    ),
    'Message' => array(
        'Subject' => array(
            'Data' => 'test',
        ),
        'Body' => array(
            'Text' => array(
                'Data' => 'This is a <b>test</b>',
                "Charset" => "UTF-8"
             ),
            'html' => array(
                'Data' => 'This is a <b>test</b>',
                "Charset" => "UTF-8"
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'ReplyToAddresses' => array(....)
));
```

Email is sent correctly but the tags are not interpreted. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: your putting html in the text part of the message body.

Comment: I've tried to send only the date html and leave blank text but does not work. I've tried everything. How do you think should be?

Comment: What happens if you put *text* (not HTML) in the text field and HTML in html?

Comment: It sends perfectly. The problem is with html tags as they arrive in the mail and are not interpreted...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the html content that should be Html. Thanks to all who helped.